# Unit Test a CMS block collection factory

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I am currently exploring the unit testing in Magento 2. I have grasp some of the fundamentals by basing on the core code but I cannot seem to create a unit test on the code below

```
$blocks = $this->blockFactory->create();

        foreach ($blocks as $block) {
            if ($block->getIdentifier() == 'terms-and-conditions') {
                return $block->getUpdateTime();
            }
        }

        return '';
```

The block factory is derived from

```
use Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory as BlockFactory;
```

Do you guys have any idea how to tackle this.